# Using the latest version of Scala gives java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function1$class

Tags: java, scala, dependencies, sbt

So I want to use the [cronish](https://github.com/philcali/cronish) library in my SBT project.

My build.sbt looks like following

```
name := "SampleName"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.4"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.philcali" % "cronish_2.11" % "0.1.3"
```

I have to mention `cronish_2.11` explicitly because `cronish_2.12` does not exist. I'm running the project in workers.scala located at `$ProjectRoot/src/main/scala`

```
import cronish._
import cronish.dsl._

object workers {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

    val payroll: CronTask = task {
      println("You have just been paid... Finally!")
    }

    payroll executes "every 5 seconds"
  }
}
```

When I run it using `sbt run` is get the following error:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1$class
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1$class
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser.<init>(Parsers.scala:225)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers$$anon$1.<init>(RegexParsers.scala:84)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers$class.literal(RegexParsers.scala:84)
    at cronish.dsl.Cronish$.literal(dsl.scala:209)
    at cronish.dsl.CronParsers$class.$init$(dsl.scala:28)
    at cronish.dsl.Cronish$.<init>(dsl.scala:209)
    at cronish.dsl.Cronish$.<clinit>(dsl.scala)
    at cronish.dsl.package$.string2cron(package.scala:7)
    at cronish.dsl.package$.<init>(package.scala:18)
    at cronish.dsl.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    at workers$.main(workers.scala:8)
    at workers.main(workers.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function1$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser.<init>(Parsers.scala:225)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers$$anon$1.<init>(RegexParsers.scala:84)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers$class.literal(RegexParsers.scala:84)
    at cronish.dsl.Cronish$.literal(dsl.scala:209)
    at cronish.dsl.CronParsers$class.$init$(dsl.scala:28)
    at cronish.dsl.Cronish$.<init>(dsl.scala:209)
    at cronish.dsl.Cronish$.<clinit>(dsl.scala)
    at cronish.dsl.package$.string2cron(package.scala:7)
    at cronish.dsl.package$.<init>(package.scala:18)
    at cronish.dsl.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    at workers$.main(workers.scala:8)
    at workers.main(workers.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

I can get it to work if I change the `scalaVersion` to `2.11.x`. But I was wonder what is causing the error? Whats the best way to make this work with my current Scala version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala does not have binary compatibility across major releases (and 2.11.x is a different major release from 2.12.x).

This means that you absolutely cannot use a library compiled against Scala 2.11 in a project that uses Scala 2.12, sorry.

You might want to:

- Downgrade your project by setting `scalaVersion := "2.11.11"`
- Wait for cronish to release a version compiled against Scala 2.12
- Try to compile cronish against Scala 2.12 (if you e.g. host a fork on github, it is possible to depend on it directly by URL in your build.sbt)